# Redirect URL is not allowed: Liferay Page Delete

Tags: liferay

[image]When I go to Liferay 6.2 page management, and I delete a page from there the page is deleted from db but I get a error that "Dockbar is temporarily unavailable".

Also the logs says:

```
Redirect URL ....controlPanelCategory=current_site.pages is not allowed
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-26][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
com.liferay.portal.NoSuchLayoutException: No Layout exists with the primary key
```

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace?

Comment: Also, which *exact* version is this on?

Comment: @OlafKock this is liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp11 ..and patch 131..after patch we are facing this problem

Comment: If you have Liferay EE, why aren't you just opening a support ticket and get it fixed? That's why you are paying for EE support in the first place, no? If there's a regression introduced by some patch, you'll want it fixed, not worked around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `redirect.url.security.mode=domain` to my portal-ext.properties worked and fixed this problem.

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue. Some links were missing/not working when we went to the webcontent edit page.
We already had the `redirect.url.security.mode=domain`, but adding all the URLs to domain allowed solved the issue:
`redirect.url.domains.allowed=t1.url.com,t2.url.com` (Liferay 6.2.)

In Liferay 7 wildcards should work `redirect.url.domains.allowed=*.url.com` according to https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html